# SMF logs me out of my site

Tags: php, bridge, smf

I have built the the bridge between my system and smf  which is working. It sets the cookie using the smf api then allows the user to login. But when the users goes back to my site which is a custom built site using standard sessions the user is logged out.

I am using the smf_1-1_api.php include to accomplish this.

with this code

```
      smf_setLoginCookie(21600, $user['login'], $passwd, true);
        smf_authenticateUser();
```

Thanks in advanced for your help

I thought I might build a bridge back to my site which logins me back in?

Answer (score 0):

This was from the session name was the same on both applications. I simply change the session name in my app and it no longer logged me out.